# Updating global variable after an If statement

Tags: python, if-statement

The variable 'k' is not updating at the end of If statement ( unless I updating it inside If statement ). Which is the right way or the explanation?thx

```
lvl = 1
k = lvl * 10
while lvl <= 10:
    user = int(input(" "))
    if user == 5:
        lvl += 1
       'k = lvl * 10'
   print(lvl)
   print(k)
```

Comment: 'k = lvl*10' is a string, not a statement. also, could you write this in a clearer way?

Comment: Is the problem that you want `k` to update automatically when `lvl` changes?

Comment: yep robbrit, that's what I wanted, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `'` surrounding the line:

```
'k = lvl * 10'
```

to become:

```
k = lvl * 10
```

Comment: hi, I wrote it between '' as I tried with that line of code and without, I guess my question should've been if a global variable is updating only if it is updated in a block of code ( that's why I was confused ), thx for reply